# DataTemplateSelector not working if ItemContainerStyle is set

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox

I have two Listboxes, default and custom. One uses DataTemplateSelector correctly and other just uses default DataTemplates never calling selector;

```
//shows correctly
<ListBox Name="testlb" ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource ffDataTemplateSelector}"/>

//now showing correctly (using default DataTemplates instead of selector)
<local:FFBox x:Name="myFFBox" ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource ffDataTemplateSelector}" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource FFItemStyle}" />
```

Both have same source

```
testlb.ItemsSource = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(FileCollectionView);
myFFBox.ItemsSource = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(FileCollectionView);
```

Obviously there is nothing wrong with DataTemplateSelector as it works correctly on testlb

Problem is `ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource FFItemStyle}"` which I use to define overall look for each ListBoxItem, contains triggers, animation etc. If it is present the Selector does not work.

```
<Style x:Key="FFItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
         <Grid x:Name="mygrid">
           <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" 
              Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"                                          
              ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"/>
```

How do I keep ItemContainerStyle and still be able to change DataTamplates with DataTemplateSelector?

**EDIT:**
Solved, we should keep it as this is one of those illogical and not well documented things in wpf.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Got it:
If you have ItemContainerStyle  defined, instead of ItemTemplateSelector one needs to use ContentTemplateSelector in ContentPresenter with DataTemplateSelector.

```
<ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter"  Content="{TemplateBinding  Content}"
               ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource ffDataTemplateSelector}"
```

Answer (score 0):

mmm code looks ok but have you tried setting ItemTemplateSelector it like this

in Generic.xaml

```
<Setter Property="ItemTemplateSelector">
        <Setter.Value>
            <helpers:ffDataTemplateSelector x:Name="ffDataTemplateSelector" />
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
```

where helpers is set like so at top of Generic.xaml

```
xmlns:helpers="using:[Namespace where ffDataTemplateSelector resides]"
```

Comment: Please see edit. Having ItemContainerStyle is the problem but I don't know how to keep it and still use selector